# How to set global rounding for DecimalFields in Django project?

Tags: python, django, django-models, decimal, rounding

I found similar [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18087777/global-decimal-rounding-options-in-django) with answers, but "setting the option in the settings.py" and "setting getcontext() in apps.py" doesn't work. Standard decimal rounding is ROUND_HALF_EVEN, but I need to set ROUND_HALF_UP.

And I repeat my question with a quote - "where in the Django application I have to set rounding option, so that it would work globally in the project?"

Comment: Which version of django you are using?

Comment: I'm using Django 1.10.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For django project can work setting decimal.DefaultContext ([py3](https://docs.python.org/3/library/decimal.html#decimal.DefaultContext), [py2](https://docs.python.org/2/library/decimal.html#decimal.DefaultContext)).

> This context is most useful in multi-threaded environments.

This is my code from `settings.py`:

```
import decimal
# Set global decimal rounding to ROUND_HALF_UP (instead of ROUND_HALF_EVEN).
project_context = decimal.getcontext()
project_context.rounding = decimal.ROUND_HALF_UP
decimal.DefaultContext = project_context
```