# Setting Decimal options globally in Django

Tags: python, django

The default rounding method for a Decimal in Python is ROUND_HALF_EVEN.

I have a Django 2.0 app that needs to use ROUND_HALF_UP in all model DecimalFields.

I have tried all 3 answers given in this question:

[Global decimal rounding options in Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18087777/global-decimal-rounding-options-in-django)

But none has worked. For example, using the apps.py method given in the second solution - I have confirmed that the context for Decimal has changed by calling

```
decimal.getcontext()
```

immediately after setting it with

```
decimal.getcontext().rounding = decimal.ROUND_HALF_UP
```

I can then confirm this by going into the Django shell and calling

```
import decimal
decimal.getcontext()
```

which reports rounding=ROUND_HALF_UP

However, if I again call

```
decimal.getcontext()
```

in the model's save method, the rounding option has reverted to ROUND_HALF_EVEN - which suggests to me that there is more than one context?

I'd like to understand if it is possible to set decimal to ROUND_HALF_UP globally and if so, where I am going wrong with my code?

I am running the app on the django development server currently and using Python 3.6.4

Comment: Have you tried this answer too  https://stackoverflow.com/a/50056807/7692463 ?

Comment: Yes, I have tried that one. Doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 1):

getcontext only applies to the current thread and won't be called when a view is executed. Instead you should set [DefaultContext](https://docs.python.org/3/library/decimal.html#decimal.DefaultContext) in either an app config or your settings.py. All other threads will automatically inherit this context.

For example, add this in settings.py:

```
DefaultContext.rounding=ROUND_HALF_UP
```

Answer (score 0):

We this to work by placing the definition at the highest `__init__` in the Django app: `config/__init__.py`.

For our purposes, we're also overwriting the rounding of the `DefaultContext`:

```
decimal.DefaultContext.rounding = decimal.ROUND_HALF_UP
decimal.setcontext(decimal.DefaultContext)
```